# Making a Custom Menu in Android

Tags: android

I'm working on making a game for the android, with a friend doing the artwork. My friend wants to do his own menu, as in, he made an image to be used as the menu.

My question is, is there a way to have onMenuOpened() activate upon pressing the menu button with no menu items in onCreateOptionsMenu(), and then from my SurfaceView class close the menu? Or simply, how can I do my own menu that's activated upon pressing the menu button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably could use [Activity onKeyDown()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) function and detects [KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_MENU) and do what you want.

Your code should be something like:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
           // Do your own menu here
           return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```